# System.Timers.Timer - How to change timer intervals on the fly?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I'm making a service. Among other things, it must read the value from registry and configure "Primary" timers' interval according to this value. Now it should do it not only in constructor phase, but also be able to change this interval when it has been changed in registry. How do I do that?

In other words, I have a code like this:

```
using System.Timers;

public static class GVARS
{
        public static Config valFromRegistry = new ConfigRegistry().Result;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int timerPeriod = (int)(uint)GVARS.valFromRegistry.Interval * 60000;

        Timer primaryTimer = new Timer(timerPeriod);
        primaryTimer.Interval = timerPeriod;
        primaryTimer.Elapsed += RunPrimaryPayload;
        primaryTimer.Start();
                
       
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void RunPrimaryPayload(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        SomeClass.SomeMethod(someArgs);
        GVARS.valFromRegistry.Interval = (int)someNewValue;
    }
}
```

Somewhere down the code I might change `valFromRegistry.Interval` and I want `primaryTimer` to respond to those changes. How do I get there?

PS. It's not really important to me how I'm gonna check for changes in registry, be it another timer or event. Whatever works.

PS2. I have a possible idea to use `System.Threading.Timer` for `primaryTimer` instead of `System.Timers.Timer` since the former has method `Change()` which I might call from another little configrationUpdateTimer every minute or so and make `primaryTimer` respond to configuration changes this way. Am I right?

Comment: Have you actually _tried_ to just change that Property? What happened?

Comment: I've read that I need to stop-start timer to reflect changes to interval property. But since I run start during constructor, I need some sort of repeatable cycle which should govern work of primaryTimer. And here my brain goes brrrrrr,.

Comment: Have you considered [PeriodicTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers#the-systemthreadingperiodictimer-class) ? Ah, no. Nevermind. That's pretty much fixed-period. You'd probably have to tear down and create new on period change. But if that's ok for you, ...

Comment: When you know explicitly that there's a change to the data why not call the timer function directly?

Comment: How do want the change to take effect? Would it be ok if it is "after next tick" or do you need it "immediately"?

Comment: It doesn't really matter for me should changes happen immediately or after extra run of timer, or in accord with other timer. Whatever works, once again. I simply need my app (designed to run as service for ages without restart) to respond to updates in its configuration in XML/Registry

Comment: I still don't understand the hidden problem here. Reread periodically the config and reapply the changed values where they are needed. Where is this a problem?   In the shown example just reapply the Interval property. And if restarting for the timer is needed then do that (i don't believe its necessary).

Comment: ^^ _"If the interval is set after the Timer has started, the count is reset. For example, if you set the interval to 5 seconds and then set the Enabled property to true, the count starts at the time Enabled is set. If you reset the interval to 10 seconds when count is 3 seconds, the Elapsed event is raised for the first time 13 seconds after Enabled was set to true."_ - [Timer.Interval - Remarks (scroll down)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.interval?view=net-7.0#remarks)

Comment: Oh ... looking back at your code, I think I get what the problem is. You need to have a handle to the timer in the class, so you can reassign to its `Interval` property. In your example it's just a local var in the `Main` function ...

Comment: I just don't get it how can I control primaryTimer.Interval. In Main there is literally nothing except for constructor for timer, and in Program contains only Main and RunPrimaryPayload. How can I address primaryTimer.Interval? it's not visible from context of RunPrimaryPayload.

Comment: As a side note the [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer) class is not thread-safe. So in case it is used from multiple threads concurrently, all access must be synchronized.

Comment: Move `Timer primaryTimer` out of `Main` as a `private static Timer primaryTimer;` field of the `Program` class. Then you can access it in other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to solve my problem by creating class with 2 Timers: one checking for config changes (master) and another (slave) is doing actual payload:

```
public class UniversalTimer
{
    public System.Threading.Timer MasterTimer;
    public System.Threading.Timer SlaveTimer;
    private int lastMainTimerInterval = 0;

    public UniversalTimer()
    {
        MasterTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(MasterTimerCallback), null, 0, 60000);
        SlaveTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(SlaveTimerCallback), null, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }
    
    private void MasterTimerCallback(object obj)
    {
        Log.Debug("[{0}:{1}:{2}] Re-reading configuration from registry", "Program", "UniversalTimer", "MasterTimerCallback");
        var currentSettings = new ConfigRegistry().Result;

        if ((int)currentSettings.Interval != lastMainTimerInterval)
        {
            Log.Debug("[{0}:{1}:{2}] Setting interval for Main Timer", "Program", "UniversalTimer", "SlaveTimerCallback");
            lastMainTimerInterval = (int)currentSettings.Interval;
            this.MainTimer.Change(0, (int)currentSettings.Interval * 60000);
        }
    }

    private void SlaveTimerCallback(object obj)
    {
        Log.Debug("[{0}:{1}:{2}] Executing main cycle", "Program", "UniversalTimer", "SlaveTimerCallback");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        MasterTimer.Dispose();
        SlaveTimer.Dispose();
    }
}
```